# Access external ms SQL Database Data From C# Plugin CRM (online version)

Tags: sql-server, database, dynamics-crm

It is possible to run a MS SQL query inside of a Dynamics 365 (Online version) plug-in, if the SQL Server is externally exposed? If it is possible then how?

Comment: External sources are addressed in the Dynamics 365 documentation. Did you read it? Do you have a *specific* question? The question is so broad that the only possible answer is a link to the docs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I do not but try to find some information about if it is possible to query data in crm (on-demand) plugin from external ms sql database. There is no info in the docs about this specific case.

Comment: [Synchronize Dynamics 365 data with external systems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn932127.aspx). It should be obvious that a hosted CRM *can* connect to on-premise systems. You just need to find out how.

Comment: Please try to edit your question. Its ambiguous. 
Few Facts: CRM Plugin cannot be on-demand. Online CRM SQL is inaccessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to connect to externally exposed MS SQL database from CRM (online version) plugin through build-in C# SqlClient. But actually the real answer is that you cannot to query externally exposed database. Whenever you try to open a connection you hit a sandbox limit, that permission type is not whitelisted (trusted), so it cannot be used. Sandbox do not support fully trusted plugin. You can read more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-HWMWdPQPfpZLLnyhZTSTxA&tduid=(adfe93a9f75d03f53fb39caba1e91dbf)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-HWMWdPQPfpZLLnyhZTSTxA)()